# Gatsby doesn't seem to build on Windows Subsystem Linux [Ubuntu]

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Note: I encountered this problem in [Part 7 of the GatsbyJS tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/tutorial/part-seven/) (previous sections worked fine).

`gatsby develop`

... appeared to trigger a successful build, but the site hangs every time upon visiting http://localhost:8000/

Recopying question from [here](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/22777) for visibility:

> Gatsby doesn't seems to build on Windows Subsystem Linux due to EACCES issues. After running yarn start / gatsby develop and a successful build, the script keeps trying to update .cache/redux and fails due to a permission error. And because of that, it keeps generating these reduxcache directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix: Update to WSL2 by following the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-kernel

Note: I still sometimes see:

> warning Error persisting state: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/home/james/code/gatsby-course-udemy/gatsbyjs-tutorials/.cache/redux' -> '[...]/code/gatsby-course-udemy/gatsbyjs-tutorials/.cache/redux.bak'

... error, but the at least the site is building, loading, and running without any apparent issues!